# Rails 4 jQuery-ui Autocomplete not reading route source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

JQuery-ui autocomplete in rails 4 not reading source when set to a URL path, but works when I manually pass an array of values in my coffee script.

```
posts_controller.rb
def autocomplete
   render json: ["Test"]
end
```

I manually entered this string "Test" to test if Jquery-ui was working.
My autocomplete route is configured as follows:

```
routes
resources :posts do
 collection do
  get :autocomplete
 end

 member do
  get "like", to: "posts#upvote"
  get "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
 end
end
```

Then in my posts.coffee file I have this:

```
jQuery->
 $("#q").autocomplete(
  source:"/posts/autocomplete",
  minLength: 2
 )
```

This does not return anything when I try to search. But when I manually key in the array of values to the coffee script, it works...like this:

```
jQuery->
 $("#q").autocomplete(
  source: ["Foo", "Bar"],
  minLength: 2
 )
```

What may be wrong here?

Comment: Can you check your rails server console to see if its showing some errors?

Comment: O yes Kumar Abinash, bingo!! I checked the rails console and it was being blocked by a `before_action require_user` in my controller. I added an exception in this restriction for the autocomplete action and it now works well. Thanks very much for the pointer.